# Execute an SQL query inside another SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, web, backend

Ok, I assume that the title is not the best title, but let me explain my problem: I'm creating a website that needs to show posts of people (anyway), and I have to show their gravatar's profile picture, so this what I did:

```
<?php 
            function get_gravatar( $email, $s = 80, $d = 'mm', $r = 'g', $img = false, $atts = array() ) {
                $url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/';
                $url .= md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) );
                $url .= "?s=$s&d=$d&r=$r";
                if ( $img ) {
                    $url = '<img src="' . $url . '"';
                    foreach ( $atts as $key => $val )
                        $url .= ' ' . $key . '="' . $val . '"';
                    $url .= ' />';
                }
                return $url;
            }
            require("db.php");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC";
            foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
                // var_dump($row);
                $user = $row['user_id'];
                $sql_user = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id = $user";
                foreach ($db->$sql_user as $row_user) {
                    var_dump($row_user);
                    echo "<img src=\"".get_gravatar($row_user['email'])."\"/>";
                }
                echo "<h2>".$row['title']."</h2><br/>";
                echo "<p>".$row['content']."</p><br/>";
            }
```

But, it doesn't work (well, it works, but it doesn't shows me the profile picture of the user, only the post).
So, I think the problem is that I can't call 2 times the variable `$db` at the same time, but I'm not sure, so that's m=why I'm asking if there is a way to fix my problem or to select 2 tables at the same time.

Comment: see your second foreach you miss to put query function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can short your logic

```
$sql="SELECT u.email "
                    . "FROM posts AS p "
                    . "LEFT JOIN users AS u "
                    . "ON u.id=p.user_id "
                    . "ORDER BY p.date DESC";
```

Comment: Could you develop? I mean, could you explain how I can use it?

Comment: This is better, as you won't be running multiple queries in your inner for loop, which adds overhead.   Also I think it should be "SELECT p.user_id,u.email " in the first part.  u and p mixed up.

Comment: just call the column you want, in you case is, `$row['email']` , this is already relate in users data.also you can get `$row['user_id']` in single `result set`

Comment: @waltron aw, your right, :) its mistake sample, or maybe we can remove taht, because only needed is email

Answer (score 1):

use `join`

```
SELECT * FROM users join posts  on users.id =Posts.user_id ORDER BY date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [JOIN](http://www.phpknowhow.com/mysql/joins/)

> JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on
>   a related column between them.

Comment: join and Union are very different

Comment: @Jens Yeah they are different...  UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements into a single result set. while JOIN clause is used to combine rows from two or more tables, based on a related column between them... he could use any of this to achieve his result...he wanted to select 2 tables at the same time..

Comment: No he can not. You can not solve a Problem with very different functions

Comment: i was suggesting to use either one of this

Comment: Yes but if OP using Union, he get never the result he/she wants

Comment: use a `GROUP BY`? maybe will help. because sub query has more than one result

Comment: Then please remove the suggestion of UNION

Answer (score 1):

you  don't apply query to  sql string   in second foreach

```
  foreach ($db->query($sql_user) as $row_user) {
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I prefer the join one, thanks :)

Comment: you prefer  a solution that is a suggestion but not the solution for you question .. ?    .. normally  the soution is acceppeted ..  and the suggestion are marked as useful ..

Answer (score 1):

see your second foreach you miss to put query function

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {



foreach ($db->query($sql_user) as $row_user) {
```

Comment: Your solution works, but I prefer the join one, thanks :)